# Instagram API without authentication

Tags: asp.net, api, instagram

Is it possible to use Instagram API and to create a web app which shows some images by their hashtags without that a person must authenticate herself? I'm using ASP.NET to develop the website

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709818/get-tagged-photo-without-access-token

Comment: Short answer is you don't need authenticate unless you are doing something on behalf of the user.

Comment: I tried on the console app of instagram api trying to execute the get method to receive the recent media with a specific tag without authentications and it said to me that that method requires an authentication. Somebody says that it requires only the client id but if so how can I do that?

Comment: You will need to register an application and get a client ID.

Answer (score 12):

Not sure about tags, but you can download any Instagram user photo feed in JSON format using `?__a=1` next to landing page address [like this](https://www.instagram.com/smena8m/?__a=1). No need to get user id or register an app, no tokens, no oAuth.

UPDATE 12 APR 2018: Facebook applied some sign/token protection on endpoints like this one and now you need to provide `X-Instagram-GIS` header and `csrftoken` cookie. Header calculated with `rhx_gis`, `csrf_token`, `user-agent` and `variables` from your request. But still, this is possible to get Instagram feed data without auth.

UPDATE JAN 2019: Check my [latest update here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33783840/819764) about how to use Google as `CORS` proxy.

Comment: Looks like a cheat

Comment: @Londeren Check my latest update about how to use Google as CORS proxy.

Answer (score -2):

yes, you need to create a client_id for your app here:

https://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/

and then call this url:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{hastag}/media/recent?callback=&client_id={client_id}&count={number of photos to return}