# show amount of Instagram followers on website

Tags: javascript, php, count, instagram

It seems like Instagram has changed certain things, because I have tried several codes on my html website to show the amount of Instagram followers on a button, but nothing works.

I tried this:

```
<?php
$account='XXX';
$instagramsource=file_get_contents('https://instagram.com/' . $account);
preg_match_all('/"userInteractionCount":"(.*?)"/', $instagramsource, $count);
$followcount=$count[1][0];
echo "$account instagram account has $followcount followers";
?>
```

Also this

```
<?php
$otherPage = 'XXX';
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.instagram.com/$otherPage/?__a=1");
if ($response !== false) {
$data = json_decode($response, true);
if ($data !== null) {
    $follows = $data['graphql']['user']['edge_follow']['count'];
    $followedBy = $data['graphql']['user']['edge_followed_by']['count'];
    echo $follows . ' and ' . $followedBy;
}
}
?>
```

And this ...

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/XXX";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
$content = $obj['query']['results']['script']['content'];
$content = str_replace("window._sharedData =", "", $content);
$content = str_replace(";", "", $content);
$content = trim($content);
$json = json_decode($content);
$instagram_follower_count = $json->entry_data->ProfilePage{0}->user->followed_by->count;
?>
```

And finally this:

```
<?php
$username = 'XXX';
$response = @file_get_contents( "https://www.instagram.com/$username/?__a=1" );
if ( $response !== false ) {
$data = json_decode( $response, true );
if ( $data !== null ) {
    $follows = $data['graphql']['user']['edge_follow']['count'];
    $followedBy  = $data['graphql']['user']['edge_followed_by']['count'];
    echo 'XXX follows:' . $follows . ' and is followed by: ' . $followedBy;
}
}
?>
```

None works.
Can anyone indicate what would work in 2021, please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the url `https://www.instagram.com/$username/?__a=1` is redirecting to login page & giving u a html response

You can check it by `echo $response`

These posts will help you [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414606/getting-basic-information-from-instagram-using-php),[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66245068/instagram-follower-count-script-has-me-stumped-php)

Comment: How would this work, please? How does the code look like then?

Comment: Check the edited post

Comment: Thanks, Dhruv, but these posts are too technical for me, I am just a newbie. It seems like Instagram has changed something lately so most scripts don't work, so I am looking for a script that I can easily configure myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram blocked access via __a=1 parameter since 2018-04-12. __a=1 must be replaced by JS and Ajax bypass. I've looked for an alternative solution. You can use javascript code inside php. For example:

```
async function instagramFollowers () {
    
    const followers = []
    
    try {
        const userInfoSource = await Axios.get('https://www.instagram.com/123/')

        
        const jsonObject = userInfoSource.data.match(/<script type="text\/javascript">window\._sharedData = (.*)<\/script>/)[1].slice(0, -1)

        const userInfo = JSON.parse(jsonObject)
       
        const mediaArray = userInfo.entry_data.ProfilePage[0].graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges.splice(0, 10)
        for (let media of mediaArray) {
            const node = media.node
            
            followers.push(node.thumbnail_src)
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Unable to retrieve Followers. Reason: ' + e.toString())
    }
    
    return followers
}
```

Other helpful links: [how to write javascript code inside php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596218/how-to-write-javascript-code-inside-php)

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-ajax-in-php-and-jquery--cms-32494

Comment: Thanks for the code. I put it between <?php and ?> and I changed 123 in the url to my username, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Page does not load at all anymore.
In the page builder it says "unexpected T_function"

Comment: Hey Fog, any solutions to this error, please?